# Scala: Polymorphism in argument type of higher order function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have stumbled across something in Scala that really confuses me. It seems that argument types for higher order functions are not polymorphic. Below is a demonstration of what I mean:

```
class A

class B extends A

def call(f: A => A):A = f(new A)

def A2A(a: A): A = new A
def A2B(a: A): B = new B
def B2A(b: B): A = new A
def B2B(b: B): B = new B

call(A2A)  // Works
call(A2B)  // Works
call(B2A)  // Error!
call(B2B)  // Error!
```

The error message is the same for both calls:

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : B => A
required: A => A
          call(new B, B2A)

<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : B => B
required: A => A
          call(new B, B2B)
```

A2A and A2B work, so it's not the return type that's causing the problem, it must be the argument type. Is this something to do with type erasure?

I don't think there's anything logically wrong with what I'm trying to do (maybe there is?) so I suspect it's a quirk with the type system?

***EDIT***

Thanks for the answers! It turns out this is my faulty logic after all. The problem is with the definition of `call`. It expects a function that takes an `A` (or subtype) as an argument.

`B2A` and `B2B` both take a `B` (or subtype) and are therefore not compatible with `call`'s definition.

I solved this problem by introducing a trait that `A` extends from called `ALike` and changed the definition of `call` so that it takes any argument that has `ALike` as a supertype.

```
trait ALike
class A extends ALike
class B extends A

def call[T <: ALike](t: T, f: T => A): A = f(t)

def A2A(a: A): A = a
def A2B(a: A): B = new B
def B2A(b: B): A = new A
def B2B(b: B): B = b

call(new A, A2A)
call(new A, A2B)
call(new B, B2A)
call(new B, B2B)
```

Comment: I think you made a type in your edit in the result type of `B2A`. It should be `def B2A(b: B): A = new A`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call(f) is expecting a function that can take in an A (or any subtype) and return an A (or any subtype). The reason 1 and 2 work is that your function definition can take A or any subtypes of A, and in 1, returns A (satisfying the condition of being A) or in 2, returns B (satisfying the condition of being a subtype of A).

The reason the latter two don't work is that you're passing in a function which can only take a B and return A or B. To see why this is a problem, assume you've got class C extends A. B2A won't be able to handle C, which means that call(f), by definition, won't be able to handle the input C, *despite being a subtype of A*. This is a compile error due to the definition of call.

Comment: Ahh, so it is my faulty logic then rather than a quirk of the type system

Answer (score 3):

The arguments of a Scala `Function` are contravariant. Which in the case of `A => A` means that you can create a function which accepts a super type of `A` but not a function which accepts a sub type like `B`.

You could define a function which takes `Any`:

```
def Any2A(any: Any) = new A 
def Any2B(any: Any) = new B

call(Any2A) // A = A@b5bddc9
call(Any2B) // A = B@62c1c65f
```

> Function1[-T1, +R]

The argument of [`Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) is contravariant and the result is covariant, which means that in a function of type `A => A`:

- You can return a `B` when an `A` is the result type (covariant) : `A2B`
- You can not accept a `B` when an `A` is the type of the parameter (`B2A` and `B2B`), but you can pass a super type of `A` like `Any` (`Any2A` and `Any2B`).

Some explanation about the contravariance (and covariance) of `Function` can be found in [*Programming in Scala, 1ed*](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#19.6)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I opted to constrain the type rather than use Any (see my edit).

Comment: I just used `Any` to show that you can use a super type as an argument.